# How to put the icons on the left side of a nav bar?

Tags: css, icons, navbar

I want to replicate the following nav bar of this site:
[Cherry Responsive Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w6Bv.png)

However, when I tried to put icons, the following happens:

[Problem with the icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St6ei.png)

The icons are outside the submenus. How to resolve this?

This line is the icon Font Awesome:

```
<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
```

And this is a submenu where I want the icon to be:

```
<li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Menu 3</span></a></li>
```

I want to place each icon within the submenus and they are aligned to the left. I'll appreciate your help because I cannot resolve my problem with other questions I researched. Thanks.

Source:
http://jsfiddle.net/mekLzupt/

Comment: If you want it to be inside the menu the Font Awesome icon must be inside the link tag. If you want the icon to be just to the left of the menu name you could use: `<li class='last'><a href='#'><i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i> <span>Menu 3</span></a></li>` . You will probably want to add a margin with CSS to make a little space between the icon and the text

Comment: Awesome! I needed to know that the last. Why your comment appears in this zone and no further? Anyways, thank to you too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your icon inside of anker tag. Try this line of code.

```
<li class='active'><a href='#'><i class="fas fa-grin-squint-tears"></i><span>Inicio</span></a></li>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. 

If I need to move the icon to the left I have to do it in CSS, right, is it?

Comment: Yes, you can move the icon to the left side by using `margin-right` property.

Comment: Mmm It doesn't work with margin-right. I try to place this in the template above.

`.last {
  margin-right: 5 px;
  }

.fas fa-star-half-alt {
  margin-right: 5 px;
}`

Those codes they don't move the text or the icon the folllowing code:

`<li class='last'><a href='#'><i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i> <span>Menu 3</span></a></li></ul>`

Comment: Man, you're awesome. Your line works pefect! I could never have discovered it in a YouTube video. Thank you for all.